# How to query DynamoDB by date (range key), with no obvious hash key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I need to keep local data on an iOS app in sync with data in a DynamoDB table. The DynamoDB table is ~2K rows, with only a hash key (`id`), and the following attributes:

- `id` (uuid)
- `lastModifiedAt` (timestamp)
- `name`
- `latitude`
- `longitude`

I am currently scanning and filtering by `lastModifiedAt`, where `lastModifiedAt` is greater than the app's last refresh date, but I imagine that will become expensive.

The best [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14836600/querying-dynamodb-by-date) I can find is to add a Global Secondary Index with `lastModifiedAt` as the range, but there is no obvious hash key for the GSI.

**What is best practice when needing to query by range using a GSI, but there is no obvious hash key?** Alternatively, if a full scan is the only option, are there any best practices to keep down the cost?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While D.Shawley's answer helped point me in the right direction, it missed two considerations for a GSI:

1. The hash+range need to be unique, yet day+timestamp (his recommended approach) would not necessarily be unique.
2. By using only the day as the hash, I would need to use a large number of queries to get the results for each day since the last refresh date (which could be months or years ago).

As such, here is the approach I took:

- Created a Global Secondary Index (GSI) with the hash key as `YearMonth` (e.g., `201508`) and range as `id`
- Query the GSI multiple times, one query for each month since the last refresh date. The queries are also filtered with `lastModifiedAt > [given timestamp]`.

Comment: Please see my answer for additional considerations. Regards.

Comment: I have same situation like you and came to the same solution. Thanks for posting this here. One remark: GSI don't need to be unique: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForGSI.html

Answer (score 45):

Although a `Global Secondary Index` seems to fit your requirements, any attempt to include `timestamp` related information as part of your `Hash Key` will most likely create what is known as "Hot Partition", which is extremely undesirable.

The uneven access will occur as the most recent items are going to be retrieved with way more frequency than the old ones. This will not only impact your performance but also make your solution less cost effective.

See some details from the documentation:

> For example, if a table has a very small number of heavily accessed
>   partition key values, possibly even a single very heavily used
>   partition key value, request traffic is concentrated on a small number
>   of partitions – potentially only one partition. If the workload is
>   heavily unbalanced, meaning that it is disproportionately focused on
>   one or a few partitions, the requests will not achieve the overall
>   provisioned throughput level. To get the most out of DynamoDB
>   throughput, create tables where the partition key has a large number
>   of distinct values, and values are requested fairly uniformly, as
>   randomly as possible.

Based on what is stated, the `id` seems indeed to be a good choice for your `Hash Key` (aka. `Partition Key`), I wouldn't change that as GSI keys work in the same way as far as partitioning. As a separate note, performance is highly optimized when you retrieve your data by providing the entire `Primary Key`, so we should try to find a solution that provides that whenever possible.

I would suggest creating separate tables to store the primary keys based on how recent they were updated. You can segment the data into tables based on the granularity that best fits your use cases. For example, say that you want to segment the updates by day:

a. Your daily updates could be stored in tables with the following naming convention: `updates_DDMM`

b. The `updates_DDMM` tables would only have the `id`'s (hash keys of the other table)

Now say that the latest app refresh date was from 2 days ago (04/07/16) and you need to get the recent records, you would then need:

i. Scan the tables `updates_0504` and `updates_0604` to get all the hash keys.

ii. Finally obtain the records from the main table (containing lat/lng, name, etc) by submitting a `BatchGetItem` with all the obtained hash keys.

`BatchGetItem` is super fast and will do the job like no other operation.

One can argue that creating additional tables will add cost to your overall solution... well, with `GSI` you are essentially duplicating your table (in case you are projecting all fields) and adding that additional cost for all ~2k records, being them recently updated or not...

It seems counter intuitive creating tables like this but it is actually a best practice when dealing with time series data (From AWS DynamoDB Documentation):

> [...] the applications might show uneven access pattern across all the items
>   in the table where the latest customer data is more relevant and your
>   application might access the latest items more frequently and as time
>   passes these items are less accessed, eventually the older items are
>   rarely accessed. If this is a known access pattern, you could take it
>   into consideration when designing your table schema. Instead of
>   storing all items in a single table, you could use multiple tables to
>   store these items. For example, you could create tables to store
>   monthly or weekly data. For the table storing data from the latest
>   month or week, where data access rate is high, request higher
>   throughput and for tables storing older data, you could dial down the
>   throughput and save on resources.
>
> You can save on resources by storing "hot" items in one table with
>   higher throughput settings, and "cold" items in another table with
>   lower throughput settings. You can remove old items by simply deleting
>   the tables. You can optionally backup these tables to other storage
>   options such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3). Deleting an
>   entire table is significantly more efficient than removing items
>   one-by-one, which essentially doubles the write throughput as you do
>   as many delete operations as put operations.

Source:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html

I hope that helps. Regards.

Comment: This is a great suggestion. Thank you for the thoughtfulness on this. It makes me wonder if RDS is a better solution, given the complexities of accessing time-based data.

Comment: Beware too that BatchGetItem is limited to 100 items.

Comment: This is a great comment, but the "hot partitions" concern is [outdated with adaptive capacity](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/). Note that there are also Dynamo [design patterns for time-series data](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/design-patterns-for-high-volume-time-series-data-in-amazon-dynamodb/) with PK being a timestamp.

Comment: The obvious thing is dynamodb is designed for OLTO and OLAP. https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/#the-difficulty-of-analytics

Answer (score 13):

You could use the "day" portion of the timestamp as the hash and use the full timestamp as the range.

Comment: Since the hash key requires an `eq` condition, would I then need to perform a query for every day that has passed since the app's last refresh? (The app locally stores a `lastRefreshedAt` timestamp). Seems like that would be more expensive than a scan.

Comment: Perhaps I could store the "year-month" portion of the timestamp as the hash key? That would significantly reduce the number of queries required when someone opens their app for the first time in, say, one year — compared to using the "day" portion. At that point, it also seems that the range key becomes irrelevant, since querying by hash key would bring in all of the items that have been updated since `lastRefreshedAt`.