# How to scan between date range using Lambda and DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm attempting to scan between a date range using a Node Lambda function.  I have the data being scanned correctly, but I can't seem to get the date expression to work correctly.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    var tableName = "MyDDBTable";
    dynamodb.scan({
        TableName : tableName,
        FilterExpression: "start_date < :start_date",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":start_date": {
                "S": "2016-12-01"
            }
        }
    }, function(err, data) {
        context.succeed(data);
    });
};
```

This currently doesn't try to return between a range, it's just looking at a single date right now. I didn't want to add an `and` to the expression until I knew this was working.

A sample document in my DynamoDB is structured like so:

```
{
    "end_date": {
        "S": "2016-12-02"
    },
    "name": {
        "S": "Name of document"
    },
    "start_date": {
        "S": "2016-10-10"
    },
    "document_id": {
        "N": "7"
    }
}
```

The `document_id` is my primary key. I'm pretty new to this whole Lamdba / DynamoDB combination, so I may have this completely set up wrong, but this is what I've managed to complete through my research.

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is given a start date and an end date, return all DynamoDB documents that have a date range within that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query DynamoDB by date (range key), with no obvious hash key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963243/how-to-query-dynamodb-by-date-range-key-with-no-obvious-hash-key)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Firstly, the scan operation is correct. The `dynamodb.scan` should be executed in a loop until `LastEvaluatedKey` is not available. Please refer this [blog](https://egkatzioura.wordpress.com/2016/07/30/scan-dynamodb-items-with-node-js/).

The lambda is not returning the result because it would have **not** found the data in the first scan. If you can extend the scan until LastEvaluatedKey is not available, the lambda is likely to return the result.

> For Query and Scan operations, DynamoDB calculates the amount of
>   consumed provisioned throughput based on item size, not on the amount
>   of data that is returned to an application.
>
> If you query or scan for specific attributes that match values that
>   amount to more than 1 MB of data, you'll need to perform another Query
>   or Scan request for the next 1 MB of data. To do this, take the
>   LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request, and use that value
>   as the ExclusiveStartKey in the next request. This approach will let
>   you progressively query or scan for new data in 1 MB increments.

**BETWEEN Operator sample:-**

```
FilterExpression: "start_date BETWEEN :date1 and :date2"
```

Comment: This was very helpful. I was under the mindset of using standard operators like `<`, `>`, `=`, etc...Upon further research, finding that `BETWEEN` was an option was very helpful.