# Query a DynamoDB table with time range

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am coming from a relational database background and currently trying to familiarise with NoSQL methodology (DynamoDB particularly). I am using Python boto3 SDK as my development environment.

I have a table called "availabilities" that has two fields called "fromTime" and "toTime". They hold time data in 24-hours format such as "16:00", or "08:30". I need to write a function that fetches all the records that the current time falls in the range of from and to times. For example current time is 16:00. The function should fetch all the rows that 16:00 falls into the range of from an to times such as 08:00 - 18:00. I am not sure if I should go with scan or query but here is how I tried it in a Lambda function:

```
import json
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from datetime import datetime


def scan(self, table_name, region, filter_expression, projection_expression):
    dynamodb_resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name=region)
    table = dynamodb_resource.Table(table_name)
    
    response = table.scan(
        FilterExpression=filter_expression,
        ProjectionExpression=projection_expression
    )
    return response
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    now = datetime.now()
    current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")
    
    fe = current_time.between(Key('fromTime'), Key('toTime'))
    pe = 'user_id'
    
    availableUserIDs = scan('availabilities', 'us-east-1', fe, pe)['Items']
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(availableUserIDs)
    }
```

I'm getting an error as follows:

```
"errorMessage": "'str' object has no attribute 'between'"
```

I am thinking about converting everything into minutes since midnight by multiplying hours by 60 and adding minutes on to it, and then comparing like that. However, I'm not sure how I can access the fromTime and toTime fields before actually running the scan function.

Comment: `fe` is a string and I would not think that `current_time.between(Key('fromTime'), Key('toTime'))` would work. That aside, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390386/how-to-scan-between-date-range-using-lambda-and-dynamodb for a more correct filter expression.

Comment: You cannot use GetItem or Query to retrieve items that have an attribute value in some arbitrary range (such as between a start and end time). Your only option would be to scan, with a filter. That said, scan is costly (performance and price) because it touches every item in the table. You don't generally want to use scan to find items, unless it's a small table.

Comment: @JonSG if my fields were of type date, this would be the way to go. However, my fields are of type time such as '16:00' and '08:30'

Comment: Maybe one possible solution could be creating 2 date objects from current day and set the time to from or to time accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### update

As you mentioned you have two different attributes, you cannot use `between` you need to state `Atrr('start').gt(time) AND Attr('end').lt(time)`

---

This should work. Top tip, never create your clients inside a function, or inside the request handler of a Lambda function, you want to re-use the client as much as possible to reduce latency.

```
import json
import logging
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from datetime import datetime
dynamodb_resource = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb_resource.Table('availabilities')

def scan(self, start_time, end_time, projection_expression):
    
    response = table.scan(
         FilterExpression=Attr('<your-key>').between(start_time, end_time)
         ProjectionExpression=projection_expression
    )
    return response
    
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    pe = 'user_id'
    start_time = '<some start time>'
    end_time = '<some end time>'
    availableUserIDs = scan(start_time, end_time, pe)['Items']
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(availableUserIDs)
    }
```

Comment: I think this is doing the exact opposite of what I needed. The start_time and end_time are attributes in table. What we are looking for is to check if current time falls in between these two attributes.

Comment: Then you cannot use between. You need to state one attribute greater than and the other less than .

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, with a slight change in logic, I was able to accomplish what I needed:`Attr('fromTime').lt(current_time) & Attr('toTime').gt(current_time)` 

Also thank you for the heads up about the clients, I fixed that part as well. Cheers!