# DynamoDB schema design to support lookup by ID and timestamp of item?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I need to design a DynamoDB schema to store items whose attributes are:

- `tid`: a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) string which is a unique identifier of the item
- `timestamp`: an [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-formatted string representing a date and time related to the item
- Other stuff...

and for the following [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) (really want to avoid having to do any [scans](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)) patterns:

- Query by `tid`
- Query by exact `timestamp`, and by relational ordering expressions (e.g., `<=`, `BETWEEN`, etc.) on `timestamp`. I.e., query all items from a certain date-time range *without* knowing their `tid`s in advance.

Is this possible to do efficiently in DynamoDB, or is there perhaps another AWS solution that would serve me better?

Answer (score 1):

Given a DynamoDB table as follows:

- partition key: `tid`, type string
- sort key: `timestamp`, type string

You can query on:

- tid = 5
- tid = 5, timestamp between 2018-12-21T09:00:00Z and 2018-12-21T15:00:00Z

Try it out using the [awscli](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/), for example to query all items with `tid=5`:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name mytable \
    --key-condition-expression "tid = :tid" \
    --expression-attribute-values '{":tid":{"S":"5"}}'
```

To query all items for `tid=5` and `timestamp between 09:00 and 15:00 on 2015-12-21`:

```
aws dynamodb query \
    --table-name mytable \
    --key-condition-expression "tid = :tid AND #ts BETWEEN :ts1 AND :ts2" \
    --expression-attribute-values  '{":tid":{"S":"5"}, ":ts1":{"S":"2015-12-21T09:00:00Z"}, ":ts2":{"S":"2015-12-21T15:00:00Z"}}' \
    --expression-attribute-names '{"#ts":"timestamp"}'
```

Note: because `timestamp` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html) in DynamoDB, you have to escape it using the expression attribute names.

You could also create the `timestamp` attribute as a number and then store epoch times, if you prefer.

To query all items with `timestamp between 09:00 and 15:00 on 2015-12-21`, regardless of `tid`, cannot be done with the same partition/sort key schema. You would need to add a [Global Secondary Index](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) something like this:

- GSI partition key: `yyyymmdd`, type string
- GSI sort key: `timestamp`, type string

Now you can query for items with a given timestamp range, as long as they're on the same day (they have the same YYYYMMDD, which might be a reasonable restriction). Or you could go to YYYYMM as the partition key allowing a wider timestamp range. At this point you really need to understand the use cases for queries to decide if YYYYMMDD (restricting queries to a single day) is right. See [How to query DynamoDB by date with no obvious hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963243/how-to-query-dynamodb-by-date-range-key-with-no-obvious-hash-key) for more on this idea.

Comment: The second query pattern I was referring to was querying by timestamp only, i.e., not having to specifying a `tid`. And since `tid` is a globally unique identifier, a composite key with `tid` as the partition key and some other key as the sort key is redundant, as it's equivalent to a simple primary key consisting of just the partition key `tid`.

What I'm looking for is a structure supporting lookups by `tid`, as well as lookups of all items belonging to a certain date-time range (without knowing their `tid`s in advance).

Comment: Apologies, misread that part of the question. The typical solution here afaik uses a GSI with a partition key that can be inferred/calculated from the timestamp and then a sort key which is the timestamp. The partition key could be something like the YYYYMMDD of the timestamp. Then you can query for items with a given timestamp range, as long as they're on the same day (have the same YYYYMMDD, which might be a reasonable restriction). Or you could go to YYYYMM as the partition key allowing a wider timestamp range, but for high i/o tables that's not ideal for sharding. Does that help?