# DynamoDB find all items after date

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table in which I store link data (`url`, `date`, `category`, `tags` etc).

I need to be able to -

- lookup items by `url` (check `url` doesn't already exist)
- find all items stored after a given `date`

Based on the above I set up the schema with `url` as primary hash key and secondary index on `date`, as follows -

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Parameters:
  TableName:
    Type: String
    Default: "my_links"
  HashAttr:
    Type: String
    Default: url
  IndexAttr:
    Type: String
    Default: date
  ReadCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 5
  WriteCapacity:
    Type: Number
    Default: 5
Resources:
  Table:
    Properties:
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: !Ref HashAttr
          KeyType: HASH
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: !Ref HashAttr
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: !Ref IndexAttr
          AttributeType: S
      GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: !Ref IndexAttr
          KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: !Ref IndexAttr
              KeyType: HASH
          Projection:
            ProjectionType: ALL
          ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacity
            WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacity
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref ReadCapacity
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref WriteCapacity
      TableName: !Ref TableName
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```

I can query the table by `date` as follows, but only using an `eq` condition -

```
ddb=boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table=ddb.Table("my_links")
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key
queryexp=Key('date').eq("2020-02-19")
for item in table.query(IndexName="date",
                        KeyConditionExpression=queryexp)["Items"]:
    print (item)
```

If I use a `gte` in place of `eq` condition I get the following -

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported
```

I can however query the table using a scan and a `gte` condition -

```
filterexp=Key('date').gte("2020-02-19")
for item in table.scan(FilterExpression=filterexp)["Items"]:
    print (item)
```

But then I'm guessing I don't need the secondary index any more and also that this will get very expensive as the table get large :-/

So I'd rather stick with a secondary index and query if possible (am I thinking about this right ?), but what do I need to do to the schema to be able to fetch all items *after* a date ?

Answer (score 1):

So this was useful -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38790120/124179

and also this -

[How to query DynamoDB by date (range key), with no obvious hash key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963243/how-to-query-dynamodb-by-date-range-key-with-no-obvious-hash-key)

In the end the answer was to denormalised the data, replacing the `date` field (and associated secondary index) with a `week` field, then searching for one or more specific weeks using `eq` query condition and joining the results (I only need a couple of weeks data)

Obviously could replace `week` with `month` for increased range but reduced granularity.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use GTE.
Queries support EQ | LE | LT | GE | GT | BEGINS_WITH | BETWEEN

Check this article https://medium.com/cloud-native-the-gathering/querying-dynamodb-by-date-range-899b751a6ef2

Comment: ```queryexp=DDBKey('date').between(low_value=args["startdate"], high_value=args["enddate"])``` still fails with `Query key condition not supported`

Comment: I missed this: Create global secondary indexes instead of secondary index

Comment: Haven't I already created a global secondary index ? The index definition is specified under `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` within the CF yaml