# How to use date filter correctly on aws dynamodb boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to retrieve items in a table in dynamodb. then i will add this data to below the last data of the table in big query.

```
client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('table')
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('created_at').gt(max_date_of_the_table_in_big_query))

#first part
data = response['Items']

#second part
while response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df[['query','created_at','result_count','id','isfuzy']]

# load df to big query
.....
```

the date filter working true but in while loop session (second part), the code retrieve all items.
after first part, i have 100 rows. but after  this code

```
while response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```

i have 500.000 rows. i can use only first part. but i know there is a 1 mb limit, thats why i am using second part. how can i get data in given date range

Comment: You didn't apply the `FilterExpression` to the second scan.

Comment: Thank you its working but it took too long. The first part did not even take 1 minute, while the second part took more than 5 minutes. (I used a very short time frame as an experiment and same data came as output in both parts.) I wonder why this is happening.

Comment: Scanning a large table is always going to be problematic. To understand options for timestamp-based queries, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963243) and optionally [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38790120/271415).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 1st scan API call has a `FilterExpression` set, which applies your data filter:

```
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('created_at').gt(max_date_of_the_table_in_big_query))
```

However, the 2nd scan API call doesn't have one set and thus is not filtering your data:

```
response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
```

Apply the `FilterExpression` to both calls:

```
while response.get('LastEvaluatedKey'):
    response = table.scan(
       ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'], 
       FilterExpression=Attr('created_at').gt(max_date_of_the_table_in_big_query)    
    )
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```